# TypeScript compiler API: problem with ts.TransformerFactory replacing nodes

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm creating a transformer that needs to replace each Call Expression `placeholder` with the code `__REPLACED__`, so I wrote this code:

`compiler.ts`

```js
import * as ts from "typescript"

const filePath = "source.ts"

const programOptions = {
    rootNames: [filePath],
    options: {
        target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES2020,
        outDir: "outdir"
    }
}

const transformerFactory: ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> = context => {
    return node => {
        const visitor: ts.Visitor = rootNode => {
            const node = ts.visitEachChild(rootNode, visitor, context)
            if (ts.isCallExpression(node)) {
                if (node.expression.getText() !== "placeholder") {
                    return node
                }
                const subsNode = ts.factory.createIdentifier("__REPLACED__")
                return subsNode
            }
            return node
        }
        return ts.visitNode(node, visitor)
    }
}

const program = ts.createIncrementalProgram(programOptions)
const entrySourceFile = program.getSourceFile(filePath)
const customTransformers: ts.CustomTransformers = { before: [transformerFactory] }
const emitResults = program.emit(entrySourceFile, undefined, undefined, undefined, customTransformers)
```

It works well if the `source.ts` file doesn't have any `placeholder` inside a anonymous function call, the code below everything works right:

`source.ts`

```js
placeholder("param") 
void function() {
    placeholder("param")
}
```

Using thats `source.ts` described above, `TypeScript Compiler API` emits what I expected:

`outdir\source.js`

```js
__REPLACED__;
void async function () {
    __REPLACED__;
};
```

But if I call this anonymous function right after creating it, I get an error if I use the following code as `source.ts`:

`source.ts`

```js
placeholder("param") 
void function() {
    placeholder("param")
}() // <---- HERE'S THE PROBLEM
```

Here's the trace error:

```sh
(node:9204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at NodeObject.getText (project_dir\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:156127:31)
    at visitor (project_dir\typescriptCompiler.ts:22:41)
    at visitNode (project_dir\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:85158:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (project_dir\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:85565:59)
    at visitor (project_dir\typescriptCompiler.ts:20:33)
    at visitNode (project_dir\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:85158:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (project_dir\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:85622:64)
    at visitor (project_dir\typescriptCompiler.ts:20:33)
    at visitNodes (project_dir\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:85211:48)
    at visitLexicalEnvironment (project_dir\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:85251:22)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:9204) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I suspect the problem is with recursion, i think somehow I'm removing the anonymous function node before accessing the `placehorlders`.

in advance thank you for your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `getText()` method in a transformer is not reliable and I would recommend never using it or other methods that consult the source file text in a transformer.

The `getText()` method goes up the tree via the parents to get the root source file node. Once there, it then looks at the source file's `text` property then gets the string between the node's start and end positions.

In the case of any nodes created while transforming, they will not have a parent set and its `pos` and `end` will be `-1` and `-1`:

```
> ts.factory.createIdentifier("__REPLACED__")
Identifier {
  pos: -1,
  end: -1,
  parent: undefined,
  // etc...
}
```

So the error occurs because `parent` is `undefined`.

It is true, that you could bypass the error you are seeing by providing the source file to `getText` by doing `node.expression.getText(sourceFile)`; however, I still wouldn't recommend this because it won't work on transformed nodes due to their range being `[-1, -1]`.

**Solution: Stay in the AST**

Instead, I would suggest to check if the expression is an identifier and look at its `escapedText` property. Roughly something along these lines (untested and you will need to adapt this for your code):

```
ts.isIdentifier(node.expression) && node.expression.escapedText === "placeholder"
```

Comment: Thanks, I set the conditions like you said and it worked perfectly, but now I'm a little confused, in various parts of my code I use `getText()` like so `ts.ImportDeclaration.importClause? .GetText() `and` ts.ImportDeclaration.moduleSpecifier.getText() `and also` ts.CallExpression.arguments.map (token => token.getText()) `, as you mentioned, getText() is not recommended for use with transformed nodes, so in those cases what should I use instead?

Comment: You can search for the specific node you're looking for and then they should each have a property on them with the text you need. If you put the code in https://ts-ast-viewer.com then you can look at the tree and see which properties on the node have the information you need. For example, a module specifier is a string literal and string literals have a `.text` property. Doing this will also make your code work better if another transformer has run on the AST before yours.